# crash when calling tone.js triggerattack or triggerrelease

Tags: p5.js, tone.js

I'm making a synth using p5js and tone.js, and i'm having an issue where it sometimes crashes with certain user inputs.

It's an intermittent problem, but multiple clicks at a certain speed will cause the sketch to crash.

I've stripped down the code to the minimum where I can still repeat the bug and I think its linked to the portamento in tone.js fm synth, and perhaps the speed at which triggerrelease releases, but i'm not sure how to fix it

here is the sketch

```
let bass
let nfrequency

function setup () {
  createCanvas(windowWidth, windowHeight);
  strokeWeight(5) 
  createSynth() 
}

function draw() {
  background(0);
  nfrequency = 220
  bass.setNote(nfrequency/4);
}

function mousePressed () {
 bass.triggerAttack();
}

function mouseReleased () {
 bass.triggerRelease();
}


function createSynth() { 
bass = new Tone.FMSynth({

  oscillator: {type: "sine"},

  portamento: 0.05 
});
bass.connect(Tone.Master); 
 
}
```

and these are the error messages that come up

```
TypeError: Failed to execute 'exponentialRampToValueAtTime' on 'AudioParam': The provided float value is non-finite.
    at undefined:7:37363

TypeError: Failed to execute 'setValueAtTime' on 'AudioParam': The provided float value is non-finite.
    at undefined:7:39588
```